# Error 500 in Redmine when I try to test email send using admin/test_email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I have just installed redmine from original image in docker. I configured Office 365 SMTP but I do not recieve emails. When I try to check if it works using admin/test_email I get:

[image: Error message]

My logs folder is empty :/

My config/configuration.yml starts like this:

```
# = Redmine configuration file
#
# Each environment has its own configuration options.  If you are only
# running in production, only the production block needs to be configured.
# Environment specific configuration options override the default ones.
#
# Note that this file needs to be a valid YAML file.
# DO NOT USE TABS! Use 2 spaces instead of tabs for indentation.

# default configuration options for all environments
default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration
  # See the examples below and the Rails guide for more configuration options:
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration
  # ==== Simple SMTP server at localhost
  #
  #  email_delivery:
  #    delivery_method: :smtp
  #    smtp_settings:
  #      address: "localhost"
  #      port: 25
  #
  # ==== SMTP server at example.com using LOGIN authentication and checking HELO for foo.com
  #
  #  email_delivery:
  #    delivery_method: :smtp
  #    smtp_settings:
  #      address: "example.com"
  #      port: 25
  #      authentication: :login
  #      domain: 'foo.com'
  #      user_name: 'myaccount'
  #      password: 'password'
  #
  # ==== SMTP server at example.com using PLAIN authentication
  #
  #  email_delivery:
  #    delivery_method: :smtp
  #    smtp_settings:
  #      address: "example.com"
  #      port: 25
  #      authentication: :plain
  #      domain: 'example.com'
  #      user_name: 'myaccount'
  #      password: 'password'
  #
  # ==== SMTP server at using TLS (GMail)
  # This might require some additional configuration. See the guides at:
  # http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration
  #
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      ssl: true
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp.office365.com"
      port: 587
      domain: "smtp.office365.com"
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "xxxxx@yyyy.zzz"
      password: "xxxxx"
```

Comment: Without logs, it's impossible to find what is wrong here. Try to get logs first, then try to reproduce your issue. If your application server can't write logs, it might be because the user running the Redmine application doesn't have the necessary permission to write to the `logs/prodution.log` file.

Comment: @HolgerJust Which user? I tried giving ownership to www-data o redmine without any success.

Comment: That depends on your setup. Often, it is `www-data` but might also be a different user. You can check this on the output of `ps axuf`. Make sure that the respective user can write to the file (the user thus also needs to be able to use all parent directories)

Comment: In any case, though, be aware that setting both `ssl` as well as `enable_starttls_auto` at the same time doesn't make sense. On port 587, you generally only want `enable_starttls_auto`.

Comment: I removed ssl setting, checked that "redmine" is the user that executes and has the ownership of all files and I even set 777 to log directory without success. No logs in folder.

Comment: You need logs. File permissions very likely have nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 uses TLS (no `ssl` option needed), and `domain` setting has to be your domain, so:

```
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp.office365.com"
      port: 587
      domain: "yyyy.zzz"
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "xxxxx@yyyy.zzz"
      password: "xxxxx"
```

Comment: I configured as you said the file but no success. But I found what happened: I cannot put as email sender a shared mailbox, it has to be a valid email address.